# Dynamically bind click event to button in template-url source

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ui-bootstrap angularjs for generating slide down's and added a button and click event, with alert message in controller but I don't get any alert or console log.

I am facing problem in generating alert on click of button which is being loaded using template-url as you can see in code below. I am sharing my sample code below.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  console.log("CTRL LOADED");
  $scope.alertMsg = function(){
    alert('hejd');
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
        <button ng-click="alertMsg()">Btn</button>
          <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
            <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
              {{heading}}
            </span>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    
    <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.isCustomHeaderOpen" template-url="group-template.html">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        Custom template with custom header template <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.isCustomHeaderOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.isCustomHeaderOpen}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      World
    </div>
    
  </uib-accordion>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do get the log "CTRL LOADED". But I am not getting alert message when I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the panel creates its own scope so you need to call the parent scope to get the alert message like so:

```
    <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="group-template.html">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:#fa39c3">
        <button ng-click="$parent.alertMsg()">Btn</button>
          <a href tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading">
            <span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">
              {{heading}}
            </span>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
        <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: right" ng-transclude></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tm5J6PeArWkn8EYVtvKG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks.. that worked... so when ever i write script i create one scope.. does this have any relation with angular config ( as i have parent child relation there also access parent scope ...).

Comment: You're I'm not sure what you mean about angular config.  I think your issue was caused because you put the button directly on the panel which is a directive.  A directive creates its own scope.  Please mark as answered to help others.  Glad I could help!